# Jackson Json not reading my json correctly

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have some json sent to my playframework site as a `byte[]` using the `POST` method.

Here is an example of the json

```
{
   "productFamily": "abcd",
   "currentVersion": "12d11e3",
   "serialNumber": "asdfasfdasdf",
   "modelNumber": "sdfsfdasf",
   "productCode": "safasdfsdfasdfsdfsd"
}
```

I'm trying to load it into a `JsonNode` using this code:

```
public static Result submit() {
    JsonNode recievedJson = request().body().asJson();
```

Eclipse debug says `recievedJson` has

```
_value = "{\r\n "productFamily": "abcd",\r\n "currentVersion": "12d11e3",\r\n "serialNumber": "asdfasfdasdf",\r\n "modelNumber": "sdfsfdasf",\r\n "productCode": "safasdfsdfasdfsdfsd"}"
```

How come my json string isn't being parsed from the request body into the `JsonNode` obj?

When I try to call JsonNode methods on `recievedJson` I dont get the expected results. for example `recievedJson.get(0)` returns `null` and `recievedJson.fields()` returns `null`

Object item = recievedJson.get("productFamily");
Eclipse debug shows item = null.

Object item = recievedJson.fields();
returns an empty iterator

Comment: What? Eclipse debug shows a representation of the object. What's wrong with it?

Comment: When I try to call JsonNode methods on recievedJson I dont get the expected results. for example recievedJson.get(0) returns null and recievedJson.fields() returns null

Comment: What does `JsonNode#get(int)` do? Please show us that `JsonNode#fields()` returns `null` in your case. Provide a reproducible example.

Comment: For example get() should return the item of an array node or if you use a string you should get the value of the field.

Comment: Right, you don't have an array node, you have an object node.

Comment: Right. So if I specify the string for the field I want I still get null

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are seeing. What version of Jackson does play use?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access array node with `get(int)` method, whereas your json is an object. Try using `get(String)` methods instead, where `String` is your key name.